# How to debug a deployed web site

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

This question kind of follows on froma previous one I posted.
I have a .net web site deployed on a server.
In certain circumstances the site falls over. Specifically, when I browse to the site from my PC (which has visual studio) to the web server using a particular dns entry.

So, I want to debug a browser session on my PC which is looking to a URL on a web server.

How can I do this?

Within VS when I attach to Internet Explorer no break point is ever reached?

Thanks in advance.

Jim

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug ASP.NET application running on remote IIS Server from VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124952/debug-asp-net-application-running-on-remote-iis-server-from-vs2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attaching to Internet Explorer isn't going to help you because the web site doesn't "run" inside IE. You need to attach to the IIS process on the web server to see what's going on.

May I suggest you start by having a look through the basics of production debugging on [Tess's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/tags/debugging+labs/). I think this would be a great place to start for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sussed it... attach to w3wp.exe on the remote server.

Made easier for me because the app I'm debugging is in its own IIS App Pool so I could see (by the user name) which one of the w3wp.exe to attach to.

Works like a dream!

Comment: That's precisely what I meant when I said "You need to attach to the IIS process on the web server to see what's going on" :)

Comment: You may have to click "Show process from all users" to get w3wp