# Website hostoed on IIS 7 displays zero results from stored procedure query

Tags: sql-server, user-interface, iis-7, web, wcf

I have a WCF REST service running on IIS on port 8000. I have implemented two GET methods in the service. I created another web application project to implement the UI for the GET's. This application is also hosted on the same IIS on port 8080. 
The GET methods call a stored proc from a SQL server db, also hosted on the same machine as IIS (this is a prototype). 
From my VS 2010 environment, I am able to display the results from the db on the UI (using GridView and ObjectDatasource as the GET methods from the referenced WCF project). However, when both projects are hosted on IIS on different ports, the UI shows the column headers but not the results. I have checked the connection string for the projects and dont see an issue there.
Any suggestions?

Comment: First, I know you say you have checked it, but make sure you check the connection strings in the actual IIS directories.  If they have been edited, publishing your site may no  overwrite them. make sure

Comment: Fire up SQL Profiler to check what is being sent to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

First, I know you say you have checked it, but make sure you check the connection strings in the actual IIS directories.  If they have been edited, publishing your site may no  overwrite them.

Filing that, you may wish to attach to the IIS process to see what is going on.  See [How to debug a deployed web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213286/how-to-debug-a-deployed-web-site).