# Visual Studio 2010 Remote Debug across domains

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I'm trying to set up remote debugging across domains.  My Windows 7 workstation running Visual Studio 2010 is on one domain and I'm trying to debug an ASP.NET app running in IIS 7 on a Widows 2003 server box in another domain.  I have found many instructions on how to set this up, this being the best, most clearly written one:  http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/11/16/remote-debugging-from-visual-studio-2010/

However, I can only seem to connect to the remote debugging monitor on the server if Visual Studio is being run as the local user on my workstation, not as the domain user.  This creates a number of challenges, such as loss of source control connectivity.  When I try to connect using the domain user I get the following error:  "Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visaul Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named 'username@servername'.  The specified account does not exist."  (I have substituted a generic username@servername for the actual values)

I have found a number of sources suggesting this will work with the domain user running VS2010 but have had no luck.  Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

First, i've read @KyleMit's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28332773/364429) on the same question and done all steps.

But, for across domain debugging also need to edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file on local computer.
Just add remote computer's ip address like this:

```
172.172.172.172     SRV-TEST-ADRESS
```

Where:

- `172.172.172.172` - ip address of your remote server
- `SRV-TEST-ADRESS` - Server's name from Visual Studio Remote Debugger
  Monitor on remote computer

You can know your server's ip address by `ipconfig` in `cmd`

[image: Visual Studio Remote Debugger Monitor]

After that, i could attach to proccess on remote computer across domain.